# Whole Array as Condition in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, syntax

I'm doing a Game of Fifteen sort of thing and I'm stuck on the syntax of arrays regarding the winning condition.

This is how I initialized the tiles:

```
string tile[4][4] = { { "15","14","13","12" },{ "11","10","9","8" },{ 
"7","6","5","4" },{ "3","1","2"," _" } };
```

This is the winning condition I want (basically all tiles in order):

```
while (tile[4][4] != { {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, { "5","6","7","8" }, { 
"9","10","11","12" }, { "13","14","15","_" } }) {...}
```

My problem is that the second one results in a syntax  error. Probably caused by the brackets specifying the position of a value instead of the size like the first initialization. I want the condition to be the whole array instead of just a specific value from that array.

I've tried doing empty brackets with the condition but again, to no avail.

How do I express the whole array as a condition?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: No, can't do. An array is a C construct that has limited functionality, for example cannot be assigned and cannot be compared. You have to do this for each element separately.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax

```
string tile[4][4] = { ... };
```

declares a built-in language array (otherwise known as a C array) -- or actually an array of arrays of `string`s. The trouble with C arrays is that they don't usually behave in the way we'd like them to. In particular in this case, checking for equality with another C array is a bit of a pain. Fortunately, there's a standard library type called `std::array<T, N>` which declares an array of type `T` and size `N` that behaves much more regularly. It's almost always better to use a `std::array` than a C array.

So instead of saying `string tile[4][4]`, we can say `std::array<std::array<string, 4>, 4> tile`. But that's a bit of a pain to type everywhere, so we'll introduce an *alias* for the type, which we'll call `board`:

```
using board = std::array<std::array<string, 4>, 4>;
```

Now we can declare a `board` just like we did before:

```
board tiles = { { "15","14","13","12" },
                { "11","10","9","8" },
                { "7","6","5","4" },
                { "3","1","2"," _" } };
```

and now what we'll also do is to declare another variable containing the winning position:

```
const board completed = { { "1", "2", "3", "4" }, /* etc... */ }};
```

(This variable is `const` because the winning position will never change). Now in your `while` loop you can say:

```
while (tiles != completed) { ... }
```

which will work as you'd like it to, and is also much easier to read than it was before.

Comment: Thanks. I really didn't know of different kinds of arrays until now. Big help, much appreciated.